# ¿Cómo puedo validar dos fechas en un formulario oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, validación, apex

Estoy buscando como validar dos fechas en oracle apex , donde la fecha final debe ser mayor o igual  a la inicial.

Hice una validación en la fecha final con código pl/sql pero no me funciono.

```
if :p1_fechafinal>=p1_fechainicial then
 return true;
else
 return false;
end if;
```

Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Solo haría un ajuste en la validación:

```
if :p1_fechafinal >= **:p1_fechainicial** then
 return true;
else
 return false;
end if;
```

el item p1_fechainicial no esta referenciado con los dos puntos.

Verificar que el tipo de validación sea: Function Body (returning Boolean) e ingresar un mensaje de error.